# IPOPT gets 'stuck'

Tags: python, optimization, controls, ipopt

I'm using IPOPT interfaced with CASadi to model a SOC system, but the solver always gets stuck. I know it found the optimal solution but it doesn't return an optimal solution. When it finds the solution it keeps returning very small variation in the objective until it reaches max_iter.

```
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
1480  4.4540346e+02 5.28e-03 5.42e+03  -1.7 8.26e-02    -  1.00e+00 5.00e-01h  2
1481  4.4546874e+02 3.48e-03 4.10e+03  -1.7 4.87e-02    -  1.00e+00 5.00e-01h  2
1482  4.4544443e+02 2.13e-03 3.96e+03  -1.7 3.36e-02    -  1.00e+00 5.00e-01h  2
1483  4.4553992e+02 8.01e-05 9.22e+00  -1.7 3.82e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
1484  4.4549114e+02 8.55e-04 8.52e+03  -1.7 7.03e-02    -  1.00e+00 2.50e-01f  3
1485  4.4550202e+02 1.75e-03 4.58e+03  -1.7 4.03e-02    -  1.00e+00 5.00e-01h  2
1486  4.4551714e+02 1.53e-04 7.55e+00  -1.7 4.29e-02    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00H  1
1487  4.4548019e+02 8.06e-04 7.84e+03  -1.7 8.26e-02    -  1.00e+00 2.50e-01f  3
```

This is the relevant code.
I split my power variable into two components because I want the 'regeneration' rate to be half compared to the regeneration rate.

```
negative = (ca.sign(power) + 1) / 2
positive = (ca.sign(power) - 1) / 2
dsoc = (-power * negative) + (0.5 * power * positive)
```

When I don't modify the regeneration rate, the solver converges to a solution.
For example, this works:

```
negative = (ca.sign(power) + 1) / 2
positive = (ca.sign(power) - 1) / 2
dsoc = (-power * negative) + (power * positive)
```

but with this code it gets stucs

```
negative = (ca.sign(power) + 1) / 2
positive = (ca.sign(power) - 1) / 2
dsoc = (-power * negative) + (0.99*power * positive)
```

thanks

Comment: My suspicion is that the sign function is non-differentiable and thus causes problems. Usually, there are better ways to model this, such as variable splitting.  We would need to see the complete model to give better advice.

Comment: I agree with Erwin. Maybe try reformulating the sign function as an MPCC or a binary optimization problem. Here is an example on formulating as an MPCC: https://apmonitor.com/online/view_pass.php?f=sign_mpec.apm  Gekko implements this as `sign2` or `sign3`: https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_methods.html?highlight=sign2#logical-functions Maybe something similar could be done with CasADi

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `sign` functions, the SOC for an energy system with non-recoverable losses can be modeled with slack variables. Below is an IPOPT solution with 50% inefficiency in dispatch of the stored energy.

[image: SOC Energy Storage]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO(remote=False)

t = np.linspace(0, 24, 24*3+1)
m.time = t

m.options.SOLVER   = 1
m.options.IMODE    = 6
m.options.NODES    = 3
m.options.CV_TYPE  = 1
m.options.MAX_ITER = 300

p = m.FV()           # production
p.STATUS = 1
s = m.Var(100, lb=0) # storage inventory
store = m.SV()       # store energy rate
vy = m.SV(lb=0)      # store slack variable
recover = m.SV()     # recover energy rate
vx = m.SV(lb=0)      # recover slack variable

eps = 0.7

d = m.MV(-20*np.sin(np.pi*t/12)+100)

m.periodic(s)

m.Equations([p + recover/eps - store >= d,
             p - d == vx - vy,
             store == p - d + vy,
             recover == d - p + vx,
             s.dt() == store - recover/eps,
             store * recover <= 0])
m.Minimize(p)

m.solve(disp=True)

#%% Visualize results
fig, axes = plt.subplots(4, 1, sharex=True)

ax = axes[0]
ax.plot(t, store, 'C3-', label='Store Rate')
ax.plot(t, recover, 'C0-.', label='Recover Rate')

ax = axes[1]
ax.plot(t, d, 'k-', label='Electricity Demand')
ax.plot(t, p, 'C3--', label='Power Production')

ax = axes[2]
ax.plot(t, s, 'C2-', label='Energy Inventory')

ax = axes[3]
ax.plot(t, vx, 'C2-', label='$S_1$')
ax.plot(t, vy, 'C3--', label='$S_2$')
ax.set_xlabel('Time (hr)')

for ax in axes:
    ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 0.5), \
              loc='center left', frameon=False)
    ax.grid()
    ax.set_xlim(0, 24)
    loc = mtick.MultipleLocator(base=6)
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Here is [additional information](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/PeriodicBoundaryConditions) on that problem.